# Efficient querying of partition master PostgreSQL table

Tags: performance, postgresql, partitioning

I'm talking about [this feature](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ddl-partitioning.html).

I have master table:

```
logstore=# \d history_log
                                   Table "public.history_log"
  Column   |           Type           |                       
-----------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------
 id        | bigint                   | NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('history_log__id_seq'::regclass)
 tstamp    | timestamp with time zone | NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
 session   | character varying(40)    |
 action    | smallint                 | NOT NULL
 userid    | integer                  |
 urlid     | integer                  |
Indices:
    "history_log__id_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Triggers:
    insert_history_log_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON history_log FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE history_log_insert_trigger()
```

and a set of child tables partitioned by tstamp column:

```
logstore=# \d history_log_201304
                               Table "public.history_log_201304"
  Column   |           Type           |                       
-----------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------
 id        | bigint                   | NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('history_log__id_seq'::regclass)
 tstamp    | timestamp with time zone | NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
 session   | character varying(40)    |
 action    | smallint                 | NOT NULL
 userid    | integer                  |
 urlid     | integer                  |
Indices:
    "history_log_201304_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "history_log_201304_tstamp" btree (tstamp)
    "history_log_201304_userid" btree (userid)
Constraints:
    "history_log_201304_tstamp_check" CHECK (tstamp >= '2013-04-01 00:00:00+04'::timestamp with time zone AND tstamp < '2013-05-01 00:00:00+04'::timestamp with time zone)
Inherits: history_log
```

So what is my problem - when I do queries that have WHERE condition constrained by tstamp directly on child tables - it works very fast.

```
logstore=# EXPLAIN SELECT userid FROM history_log_201304 WHERE tstamp >= (current_date - interval '3 days')::date::timestamptz AND tstamp < current_date::timestamptz AND action = 13;
                                                       QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using history_log_201304_tstamp on history_log_201304  (cost=0.01..8.37 rows=1 width=4)
   Index Cond: ((tstamp >= ((('now'::cstring)::date - '3 days'::interval))::date) AND (tstamp < ('now'::cstring)::date))
   Filter: (action = 13)
```

But when I try to do the same on master table - it goes to Seq Scan:

```
logstore=# EXPLAIN SELECT userid FROM history_log WHERE tstamp >= (current_date - interval '3 days')::date::timestamptz AND tstamp < current_date::timestamptz AND action = 13;
                                                                    QUERY PLAN

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------
 Result  (cost=0.00..253099.82 rows=1353838 width=4)
   ->  Append  (cost=0.00..253099.82 rows=1353838 width=4)
         ->  Seq Scan on history_log  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=4)
               Filter: ((action = 13) AND (tstamp < ('now'::cstring)::date) AND (tstamp >= ((('now'::cstring)::date - '3 days'::inte
rval))::date))
         ->  Index Scan using history_log_201203_tstamp on history_log_201203 history_log  (cost=0.01..9.67 rows=1 width=4)
               Index Cond: ((tstamp >= ((('now'::cstring)::date - '3 days'::interval))::date) AND (tstamp < ('now'::cstring)::date))
               Filter: (action = 13)
         ->  Index Scan using history_log_201204_tstamp on history_log_201204 history_log  (cost=0.01..9.85 rows=1 width=4)
               Index Cond: ((tstamp >= ((('now'::cstring)::date - '3 days'::interval))::date) AND (tstamp < ('now'::cstring)::date))
               Filter: (action = 13)
         ->  Index Scan using history_log_201205_tstamp on history_log_201205 history_log  (cost=0.01..10.39 rows=1 width=4)
               Index Cond: ((tstamp >= ((('now'::cstring)::date - '3 days'::interval))::date) AND (tstamp < ('now'::cstring)::date))
               Filter: (action = 13)
         ->  Index Scan using history_log_201206_tstamp on history_log_201206 history_log  (cost=0.01..10.32 rows=1 width=4)
               Index Cond: ((tstamp >= ((('now'::cstring)::date - '3 days'::interval))::date) AND (tstamp < ('now'::cstring)::date))
               Filter: (action = 13)
         ->  Index Scan using history_log_201207_tstamp on history_log_201207 history_log  (cost=0.01..10.09 rows=1 width=4)
               Index Cond: ((tstamp >= ((('now'::cstring)::date - '3 days'::interval))::date) AND (tstamp < ('now'::cstring)::date))
               Filter: (action = 13)
         ->  Index Scan using history_log_201208_tstamp on history_log_201208 history_log  (cost=0.01..10.35 rows=1 width=4)
               Index Cond: ((tstamp >= ((('now'::cstring)::date - '3 days'::interval))::date) AND (tstamp < ('now'::cstring)::date))
               Filter: (action = 13)
         ->  Index Scan using history_log_201209_tstamp on history_log_201209 history_log  (cost=0.01..10.53 rows=1 width=4)
               Index Cond: ((tstamp >= ((('now'::cstring)::date - '3 days'::interval))::date) AND (tstamp < ('now'::cstring)::date))
               Filter: (action = 13)
         ->  Index Scan using history_log_201210_tstamp on history_log_201210 history_log  (cost=0.01..11.83 rows=1 width=4)
               Index Cond: ((tstamp >= ((('now'::cstring)::date - '3 days'::interval))::date) AND (tstamp < ('now'::cstring)::date))
               Filter: (action = 13)
         ->  Index Scan using history_log_201211_tstamp on history_log_201211 history_log  (cost=0.01..11.87 rows=1 width=4)
               Index Cond: ((tstamp >= ((('now'::cstring)::date - '3 days'::interval))::date) AND (tstamp < ('now'::cstring)::date))
               Filter: (action = 13)
         ->  Index Scan using history_log_201212_tstamp on history_log_201212 history_log  (cost=0.01..12.40 rows=1 width=4)
               Index Cond: ((tstamp >= ((('now'::cstring)::date - '3 days'::interval))::date) AND (tstamp < ('now'::cstring)::date))
               Filter: (action = 13)
         ->  Index Scan using history_log_201301_tstamp on history_log_201301 history_log  (cost=0.01..12.35 rows=1 width=4)
               Index Cond: ((tstamp >= ((('now'::cstring)::date - '3 days'::interval))::date) AND (tstamp < ('now'::cstring)::date))
               Filter: (action = 13)
         ->  Index Scan using history_log_201302_tstamp on history_log_201302 history_log  (cost=0.01..12.35 rows=1 width=4)
               Index Cond: ((tstamp >= ((('now'::cstring)::date - '3 days'::interval))::date) AND (tstamp < ('now'::cstring)::date))
               Filter: (action = 13)
         ->  Index Scan using history_log_201303_tstamp on history_log_201303 history_log  (cost=0.01..252959.45 rows=1353824 width=
4)
               Index Cond: ((tstamp >= ((('now'::cstring)::date - '3 days'::interval))::date) AND (tstamp < ('now'::cstring)::date))
               Filter: (action = 13)
         ->  Index Scan using history_log_201304_tstamp on history_log_201304 history_log  (cost=0.01..8.37 rows=1 width=4)
               Index Cond: ((tstamp >= ((('now'::cstring)::date - '3 days'::interval))::date) AND (tstamp < ('now'::cstring)::date))
               Filter: (action = 13)
```

What's happening here? Why queries to master table isn't just as fast?

I have `constraint_exclusion` set to `on`.

**Edit**: I found solution by accident and writing it here for the sake of readability.

Till today I had wrong constraints - my `tstamp` column is of `timestamp WITH time zone` type, constraints were build on `timestamp WITHOUT time zone`. I fixed that, fixed my queries to have type casts - but still queries to master table took minutes instead of seconds. That was my last option so I went to SO. During conversation I went to DB and issued `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to all child tables to get some actual numbers - and after that queries on master table became fast!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query should be just as fast.  The seq scan is being performed on the master table *only*, which, given a properly-configured partitioned table, should contain *no rows at all*.

Consider using `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` so you can see exactly how long the query is taking.  The difference between the two should be negligible.

---

The actual problem appears to be that the query is executed on child tables that will not return any results.  Presumably your question boils down to: why are the child tables where the `CHECK` constraint cannot possibly be met still being searched?

There is [a thread on the pgsql-bugs mailing list](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/Pine.LNX.4.33.0206031236310.12984-100000@ron) about this very issue.  Your `tstamp` column is a `timestamp with time zone`.  The check cannot be used as the expression in your `WHERE` clause is a `date` value, not a timestamp.  Consider using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead of `CURRENT_DATE`.  If you need to query from midnight, then keep your current query, but add a cast to the exact same type that the `tstamp` column has (`::timestamp with time zone`).

Comment: It takes AGES. How could I check if my master table for some reason still contains rows? I believe all queries to it are proxied to child tables...

Comment: @skaurus The queries are indeed proxied, as though you had executed the query on each table (including the master) and placed `UNION ALL` between them.  What's probably taking time is not the query on the actual master table, but the index scan on the other child tables.

Comment: Errm... Just to give some actual numbers I went to DB and issued `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to all childs tables (it took about 2.5 sec in sum); then I issued same command to master table - and it took 2 seconds too! I'm embarassed. That wasn't true even few hours ago. Little background - till today I had constraints on each table with `timestamp WITHOUT time zone` and I've just fixed it - but didn't seen any changes (EXPLAIN ANALYZE on master table nearly killed my app). That's why I decided to ask for help. And now - all is good. It seems that ANALYZE of all child tables was needed :-) Thank you!

Comment: @skaurus No problem. It's the common "after asking for help I found the problem" occurrence. :)

Comment: Indeed :) Considering new part of your answer - I believe I have type casts in provided examples.